# Find failed validators asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, logging

I have a page, where I want to log every validation message which the user failed to meet the requirements the associated field.

The problem is my postback/button click never occurs (maybe because of clientside validation), and therefore the logging never takes place before the user actually got every field right (no validation errors).

The button click event method:

```
protected void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.Validate();
    if(Page.IsValid)
    {
        //code
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (IValidator validator in Validators)
        {
            if (!validator.IsValid)
            {
                PageValidatorErrors error = new PageValidatorErrors
                              {
                                  WebsiteID = AppState.WebsiteID,
                                  Page = Request.Url.AbsolutePath,
                                  URL = Request.Url.ToString(),
                                  UserIP = Tools.GetIP(),
                                  ErrorMessage = validator.ErrorMessage,
                                  CreatedDate = DateTime.Now
                               };
                pageValidatorErrorsRep.insert(error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas, how I could log theese messages?

**Edit:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validatePage()
    {
        if (window.Page_IsValid != true)
        {
            //Page_Validators is an array of validation controls in the page. 
            if (window.Page_Validators != undefined && window.Page_Validators != null)
            {
                //Looping through the whole validation collection. 
                for (var i = 0; i < window.Page_Validators.length; i++)
                {
                    window.ValidatorEnable(window.Page_Validators[i]);

                    //if condition to check whether the validation was successfull or not. 
                    if (!window.Page_Validators[i].isvalid)
                    {
                        var errMsg = window.Page_Validators[i].getAttribute('ErrorMessage');
                        alert(errMsg);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Oh, I see, you are asking how to hook into the client side javascript that the asp.net validators emit.

Comment: thanks for the validator loop sample, I was just about to go write it on my own :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is part of the solution, you can get the validates/true false by invoking it client side:

http://razeeb.wordpress.com/2009/01/11/calling-aspnet-validators-from-javascript/

```
function performCheck()
{

if(Page_ClientValidate())
{

//Do something to log true/ false
}

}
```

Comment: This might be the trick, do you know how I get the "failed" validators or could I somehow call the C# method?

Comment: Here is the link to the MSDN doc for the JS library that the validators work with, from my brief reading, you don't have much to work with: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338815(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Thanks, I am now able to loop through the validators and alert if its not valid. Just need to extract the error message now, for some reason it's null for every validator.
I've added the javascript to the topic.

Answer (score 2):

Try to change EnableClientScript property on all validators to false. All your validations will occur only on server side.

Comment: Yeah, this made the postback work, how ever the feature with validation on the fields as you type or click next field is gone ofc. I would like to keep this if possible.

Comment: I think this may be the best bet.  Get rid of the page validators and do it all server side.  That way you have a lot more control over what to log.